# How to Run embedded DEX code directly from APK

Tags: android, gradle, dex, android-10.0

First alpha of Android Q is released. It supports running embedded DEX code directly from APK. How to enable it in gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

As per android developers documentation:

> You can now tell the platform to run embedded DEX code directly from
>   your app’s APK file. This option can help prevent an attack if an
>   attacker ever managed to tamper with the locally compiled code on the
>   device.
>
> To enable this feature, set the value of the android:useEmbeddedDex
>   attribute to true in the  element of your app’s manifest
>   file. You must also build an APK that contains uncompressed DEX code
>   that ART can access directly. Add the following options to your Gradle
>   or Bazel configuration file to build an APK with uncompressed DEX
>   code:

**Gradle**

```
aaptOptions {
   noCompress 'dex'
}
```

**In manifest file:**

```
<application
        ...
        android:useEmbeddedDex="true">
...
</application>
```

> Keep in mind that the this attribute is only used in API level 28 and higher.